# Certificate Issues while Digitally Signing Windows Exe File

Tags: security, certificate, code-signing, uac, sign

I have created a small windows executable and I need to digitally sign before delivering. The main reason is to replace "Unknown Publisher" line with company name in UAC dialog.

I found the tool (signtool) and commands to sign the application. The one core requirement is a valid digital certificate. As we already have digital certificate issued for our company's website so I tried to use that certificate for signing, but I am getting an error `0 certs were left`.

Based on my research, this error occurs if:

1. Certificate is expired
2. Certificate is invalid
3. cmd is not running as Administrator

But this is not the case here. As certificate is not expired and I installed it on my system and it has "Certificate is OK" status, and I am running cmd as administrator. So I have no clue, what's wrong.

**Questions**:

1. Does the regular SSL certificate can be used for signing executables or do they have some different kind of certificates for this purpose?
2. What is the appropriate way to convert `.pfx` certificate from `.cer` and `.key` file? (the most common method seems to be `pvk2pfx` but I didn't found a way to convert `.key` into `.pvk` so I used `openssl.exe`)
3. Is there any limit for signing executable from a certificate? (e.g. this certificate can be used for signing 5 applications only)

Comment: Your certificate probably does not say it's a valid code signing certificate (an extended key usage).  (So for question 1 the answer is usually "no")

Comment: Yes, generally TLS leaf certs (& private key) like that are only capable of performing *entity authentication*, where the entity in this case is of course shown in the Distinguished Name (DN), particularly the Common Name (CN) containing the name of the server.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, got that I would need separate certificate for signing executables. Can you guys answer the question no. 3?